# How do I add reference in vb.net without Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, reference, compilation

I have found some free compilers online, but I can't figure out how to add external references to any of them. Is there a special `Imports` statement I can use, so that VB.NET will go looking for a third party .dll in a certain relative path, so that I don't have to add references through Visual Studio? The specific reference I am trying to add first is the DI interop for [SAP B1](http://www.sap.com/product/enterprise-management/business-one.html), but this probably isn't going to be the only one I will need to add.

I know that I can add a `/reference` to add a reference in a command line compilation, if I am using Microsoft's command line compiler, but that seems to be against the license for my client now. I gather the old Express 2010 versions could compile and add references without revenue restrictions, but I am looking for syntax on how to tell a compiler to add a reference, not a software recommendation (since I don't think I can still get those Express editions).

Comment: references are writting in vbproj file... But I don't know if compilers alone will read that. You can add manually the reference. I don't get why you can't use VS CE to finish the work...

Comment: @Jaxedin I can do whatever I want... but if I agree to the whole VS CE license, including the 5th bullet point in 1.2 of https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/mt171547/, I become a liar if I don't abide by the agreement I voluntarily made. My ethics inform me that my family's groceries are more important than my integrity, but not more important than at least the time and effort required to investigate alternatives.

Comment: +1 for professional integrity!  I'm not offering legal advice, but I believe the restrictions apply using VS itself.  I would think that you could always use a open source IDE like SharpDevelop to write and test your code without violating the VS conditions.

Comment: Why can you not get the old express editions?

Comment: Well, you can try add the reference in the vbproj as I said before. You will see references added using the <Reference> Tag. That sould do it, IDE wise. Every reference there it's add to the project.

Comment: http://visual-basic.soft32.com/free-download/?dm=1

Comment: .Net framework is free and `msbuild` is part of it. You can write all the code in notepad for that matter and add references to `*.??proj` file, build it using msbuild.

Comment: If you believe 2010 Express is free is restrictions, you can still download it at [http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9709969](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9709969).

Comment: Does this actually fall down onto your shoulders if it's their code? I'm curious if it does or not.

Comment: Your use of the word 'client' implies that 1.2.5 doesn't apply - that's his revenue, not yours. Seems you are covered by 1.1. But IANAL

Comment: Is it an enterprise, if ***not*** for that matter you can use Visual Studio Community Edition to develop commercial applications.  Commercial use is limited to 5 individual users (concurrently) per company but only for companies that do not qualify as an "enterprise". ***Note: there are some restrictions to this*** and I'm not an attorney, just shedding some light for you. Also if he owns the code and needs you to continue writing code to make his business flow, I'm sure a few thousand dollars is better than paying thousands in legal fees if found not compliant with Microsoft.

Comment: @Jinx88909 As a professional, if I I am doing something that I know puts any aspect of my client's business in jeopardy, that puts my reputation in danger at minimum, certainly my professional certifications, and I can clearly see how I might be liable for civil damages to the client, if not to the company that gives provides the license.

Comment: @peterG As a PM, most of my services involve managing projects and developers. I am a contractor, but the best pay scheme for this client is hourly, and yes the client owns every line of code I write or add to the project. On the other hand, when I pay a fixed price for X lines of code from a subcontractor, the subcontractor is working under 1.1.

Comment: @Zaggler You know, I wouldn't think that any of my clients would be considered 'enterprises', but it appears that Microsoft has a different opinion on that definition. In the license terms linked in a previous comment, the 'enterprise' you quote is defined as either 250 computers (seems reasonable) or 1M in revenue. For a retailer, one can easily sell 1M worth of products, and it is not unreasonable that such a retailer may have no IT personnel.

Comment: @CWilson I agree however I very much doubt you would be taken to court. Microsoft would advise if they found out giving you time to adjust your licence. What I'd personally do is advice your client and provide the solution (in writing) it's then down to them. We spend thousands on licensing and it's never right, we exceed what we think we need and then end up hitting the limit. Microsoft need something to justify the requirement of upgrading and charging for that upgrade. I agree you should upgrade but you've time to do that. Speak with Microsoft and ask for advice if in doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as @Jaxedin and @T.S. said in comments to the question, but I wasn't aware of the existence of the `MSBuild` software.

I had read in various places in reference to `MSBuild` comments like "And keep in mind that for now, you’ll need to have Visual Studio 2015 installed in order to build the first time." ([MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/03/18/msbuild-engine-is-now-open-source-on-github/)), and just took them for face value.

Being able to put the references inside an XML .vbproj is much easier than I had been imagining. Something like:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <Name>System</Name>
      <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>...\systemDir\System.dll</HintPath>
      <ReferenceOutputAssembly>True</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```